# Flask- Redirect Behind Load Balancer in AWS

Tags: python, flask, load-balancing

I'm running into a small problem with redirecting in Flask from behind a load balancer (in AWS). Essentially, I want to call `return redirect("/login")`, which works, however, I'm getting a connection reset error in-browser, which I suspect is being caused by the load balancer configuration (i.e. I try to redirect without going throw the load balancer, connection gets reset). Does anyone have any suggestion to get around this? I thought about just returning the view or some simple HTML.. Thanks!

Comment: Try redirecting to your full website path (www.example.com/login).

Comment: Also, see http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/47/